# Bluetooth stopped working after wake from sleep

Tags: suspend, bluetooth, 19.04

After I put my computer to sleep, my bluetooth didn't work.

I reinstalled bluez [following the instructions in this post](https://ar.al/2018/07/29/fix-for-no-bluetooth-found-error-after-wake-from-sleep/) but it didn't work.

**rfkill list** gives me:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04.

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I run

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

I have no output. Seems like my bluetooth adapter is not detected. That's strange because it was working well before...

I booted Ubuntu from a USB stick and bluetooth was disabled too.

**UPDATE 2**

I updated my BIOS thinking it would re-detect / activate the bluetooth adapter but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the computer? Also restart the devices and make the device discoverable

Comment: @saitam Yes I restarted my computer many times. My devices are discoverable, but since I cannot enable bluetooth in my Settings, it's normal I cannot see my mouse or keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried instead of restarting it to power it off and on again? (this worked once for me when I had bluetooth issues) Also have you tried to set bluetooth in your BIOS off and on?

Comment: Does `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth` do anything?